# FPDF multicell alignment not working

Tags: php, fpdf

I have this multicell in my pdf:

```
$pdf->multicell(115,6,$name,1,0,'L',1);
```

But it turns out that the text is right aligned instead of left aligned.

I found the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386068/annoying-bug-of-fpdf-multicell) but I don't get his solution, what does "I had to set any font" mean? I can't comment on his answer because my reputation's not enough to give comments.

Comment: Have you set a font (using `$pdf->SetFont(...)`) before calling `$pdf->MultiCell(...)`?

Comment: Yep. It is `$pdf->setFont('times','',8);`

Comment: Off-topic, I know. Do you know TCPdf (http://tcpdf.org)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `MultiCell` gets at most 6 arguments, not 7. The problem here is, that you supply `0` for alignment, not `'L'`. See [the documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm) for details.

Answer (score 5):

this is the Syntax for Multicell

```
$pdf->MultiCell(100,3,"We declare " ,1,'L',false);
```

you can do it now