# PHP - FPDF Multicell function does not make a new line

Tags: php, html, web, fpdf

I'm trying to make a newline inside a multicell. What I've done is:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(90,10,'test'.'\n'.'test',1,0,'C',1);
```

According to the manual the multicell should parse the '\n' character and render a newline but it does not (it prints the two byte string '\n' alongside with the actual text)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'` (or even `PHP_EOL` predefined constant). Use double quotes.

Related:

- [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)
- [FPDF multicell alignment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865350/fpdf-multicell-alignment-not-working)

Comment: thanks, you made my day! However, I should have expected '\n' to be a single byte value and "\n" to be a two byte string, like in ANSI C style

Comment: @G_G You are welcome. Missing your point... Did it helped? Or there any issues?

Comment: it worked. However, now multicell is trying to align text on the right   even with the 'C' parameter. FPDF is a good library but string managing is soooo clumsy...

Comment: @G_G As mentioned [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm), try to fix argument count `$pdf->MultiCell(90,10,'test'.'\n'.'test', 0,'C',1);`

Comment: thank you again. PHP doesn't tell you anything, it interprets the code straight away on a best effort basis